# Проблема с календарем на сайте

Tags: wordpress

Вот такая проблема: kroshkinbuka.ru обратите внимание на календарь с правой стороны под подпиской. Как сделать, чтобы он не вылазил? P.S кидаю ссылку на сайт потому что не могу добавлять картинки из-за низкой репутации. Движок WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

А это у вас шаблон такой! Чья-то (не знаю чья) русская переделка из Малины: http://newwpthemes.com/malina-free-wordpress-theme/ Изучайте исходники! Попробуйте копнуть sidebar.php, но я не очень уверен. В этом конкретном шаблоне не ковырялся.

Comment: Посиотрел сейчас эту тему (Малину) - и точно! Там в файле sidebar-right.php надо закомментить строчки:<li> <h2>Calendar</h2><?php get_calendar(); ?> </li>